# JQGrid : How to create a drop-down on the column header

Tags: drop-down-menu, jqgrid

I want to create a drop-down list on JQGrid header column and populate the drop-down with values from the Velocity template Array.
I have the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#activityTab").jqGrid(
            {
                datatype : "local",
                width: 100,
                colNames : [
                        headers.date, headers.method, 
                        "javascript:showDropDown();", 
                        headers.payFrom,
                        headers.confirmCode, headers.amount,headers.status ],
                colModel : [ {
```

......

How can I call a method to populate the a particular header column as above.